# Rendering web files without routing + layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I want to start a new AngularJS single page application in ASP.NET 5 (Visual Studio 2015).  I will only be using ASP.NET for its WebAPI functionality and not for view rendering (Razor).

Therefore I'd prefer it if I didnt have to have a `HomeController` and `_Layout.cshtml` from which to bootstrap my Angular app.

Is there a way to remove this and just get ASP.NET to return a static initial page? I will do all my routing via AngularJS

**Update**

As per @Phills suggestion I have put `index.html` into `wwwroot`.  If I navigate to `http://localhost:62583/index.html` it works but does not if I navigate to `http://localhost:62583/`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Place your file inside wwwroot/ (e.g. called index.html), and then ensure the following is present in your Startup.cs Configure method:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();   // Allows index.html to be used automatically
app.UseStaticFiles();    // Must be AFTER UseDefaultFiles
app.UseMvc();            // Required for your API controllers
```

Incidentally, _Layout.cshtml is not required even if you stick with using HomeController - you just need to remove the reference to it from Views\Shared_ViewStart.cshtml.  If you went this way, you would place all of your content in Views\Home\Index.cshtml.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. This is so nice! I assume you cannot do this with ASP.NET 4? I had wanted to for ages but assumed it was not possible...

Comment: Yes, you can do it in the previous version.  In MVC5 (previous version), static files are used as long as they don't match an MVC route, so simply remove the reference to RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes from your Application_Start

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `index.html` page in the root of your app, and remove the `HomeController`, if no route is found it will pick up the `index.html` page instead.

Comment: Define root of the app? I stuck one in wwwroot and when I navigate to `localhost/` it doesnt pick it up, any ideas?

Comment: You're in Visual Studio, put it in the root of your Web Application Project.

Comment: Im in VS2015 from which all web files are served from wwwroot.  Tried it from within there and within the top level web project folder and that didnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Your views don't necessarily have to have a layout page. You will still be returning a cshtml view from your controller, which will basically be a static HTML that starts your Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't especially since you are going to develop a Angular JS application you will be able to handle templating using AngularJS itself.

Instead of layout page you can have index.html and you can use <ng-view/> tag you render partial views.

You need to have some routing setup similar to MVC

```
  angular.module("myApp",["ngRoute"])
            .config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider.when("/home",{
                    templateUrl:"/views/home.html"
                });
                $routeProvider.when("/placeorder",{
                    templateUrl:"/views/placeOrder.html"
                });


                $routeProvider.otherwise({
                    templateUrl:"/views/home.html"
                });
            });
```

You view will look something like this

```
<body>
  <ng-view/>
</body>
```